# JUnit test method for each method in a program

Tags: java, junit

I wrote a JUnit testcase for the following program.

```
 public class Item {

    private int quantity;
    private int threshold;

    public int getQuantity(){
        return quantity;
    }

    public Item(int quantity){
        this.quantity= quantity;
        threshold = (int)(0.25* (float)quantity); //t=2
    }

    public int Add(int num){    
            return quantity= quantity+num;
    }

    public int Deduct(int num){
        if(num<threshold){
            quantity= quantity-num;
            return (quantity);
        }

        else{
            return -1;
        }
    }

    public String StockLevel(){
        return ((quantity<threshold) ? "under stock" : "over stock");
    }

}
```

**JUnit Testcase**

```
public class ItemJunit {
    @Test
    public void test(){

        Item i= new Item(8);
        assertEquals(12, i.Add(4));
        assertEquals(11, i.Deduct(1));  
    }
```

}

I showed my teacher the answer but he told me that the answer was partially right and that I should write a test method for each method in the program.
How am I supposed to do that?

Comment: Instead of just `test()`, create 2 methods in your test class: `testAdd` and `testDeduct`

Comment: You should write a `@Test` method for each method in your program. `public void testAdd()` where you test OK, bad, and edge cases on the `add()` method, and `public void testDeduct()` where you do the same on `deduct()`, for example.

Comment: @HuguesMoreau And one for `StockLevel()`.

Comment: @ Test for Add, @ Test for Deduct

Comment: Also, change your method names to start with a lowercase character.

Comment: Btw, did you consider asking your teacher this question? They'd know best what they meant with their feedback... and that's what they're there for. :)

Comment: @yshavit I did not ask him because I do not know if he will reply to my mail promptly and I have a paper which will cpver JUnit tomorrow so it might be late till he replies.

Comment: should the `@Test` methods be in the test class or in the in the program?

Comment: @MargoRothSpiegelman test methods are not code you run in production so they should not be in the classes you are testing. Also having the test classes extra has advantages like the isolated setup of a test or that systems like maven can enforce running the unit tests before each build. You can imagine it like a voltage measure device build on your coffee machine. This does not make much sense :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each test method in a UnitTest  should verify *exactly one expectation* about the behavior of the unit under test.

This means that you not only have to write a separate test method for each *public* method in your *class under test* (cut) but you also need to write test method for each separate *expectation* about how your cut works.
Also you (usually) have only one `assert` per test method:

```
public class ItemJunit {
    @Test
    public void addingFourtoEightReturnsTwelve(){
        Item i= new Item(8);
        assertEquals(12, i.Add(4));
    }
    @Test
    public void addingOnetoMaxIntOverflows(){
        Item i= new Item(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        assertEquals(Integer.MIN_VALUE, i.Add(1));
    }
    @Test
    public void subtractOneFromTwelveReturnsEleven(){
        Item i= new Item(12);
        assertEquals(11, i.Deduct(1));  
    }
}
```

---

The reason is:

If you have only one test method with many asserts the first failing assert exits the test. This means in your case: if your first check `assertEquals(12, i.Add(4));` fails you have no information wether your `Deduce` method works or not.

If you have separate test methods with a single assert each and a clear expectations as the test methods names you can tell by the name of the failed test method what the problem is.

Comment: I like this answer, but I think an explanation why you should do that would make it even better.

Comment: @Rhayene Thanks for the comment, Do you like my amendment?

Comment: yes, this explanation shows, that the way we do it isn't only a paradigm but has a very practical reason, I like it :)

Answer (score 0):

When you are using Eclipse IDE you can select "class under test" when creating a new JUnit Testcase. For each method a @Test-Method will be created by Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You should use your all methods written in Item class to test your program completely. As I can see, you are not using StockLevel() and getQuantity() any where in your program. Also, it is not a good practice to use private field by its name. You should generate getters and setters to provide complete access.
Also your method name's are not as per java specifications. java specification says that methos name should be camelCase.